# C++ stoi: none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I am coding an exercise relating to string: Input a string (doesn't matter either char[] or C+11 string so I chose the latter) then find the longest (has most characters) ascending substring inside the given string. The idea that I have is scan through the whole string and compare `str[i]` with `str[i+1]`. I used `stoi` to convert each character into int, which looks like this

```
if (stoi(str[i]) < stoi(str[i+1]))
```

but it instead gave me error:

```
error C2665: 'std::stoi': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

How can I fix it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you read the whole error message it should tell you that [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) expects *strings*, not single characters.

Comment: "I used stoi to convert each character into int" just don't, use `char`s directly

Comment: `char` is an integer type - you don't need to convert anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stoi` is used to convert a `std::string` to an integer.  `std::string::operator[]` gives you the character at the supplied index, which is not a `std::string` and therfore cannot be used with `stoi`.

Since you have a character you can just compare those directly since all character types are integers.  So

```
if (stoi(str[i]) < stoi(str[i+1]))
```

becomes

```
if (str[i] < str[i+1])
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::stoi` converts a string representation of a number into the number itself: `stoi("42")` should be equal to 42. What you need is a char-to-char comparison which is done as is, without any extra conversions:

```
std::size_t i{};
while(i < str.size() - 1 && str[i] < str[i + 1]) ++i;
```